# How to sum HashMap values in lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, hashmap

I want to sum a list of double variable that are values of a Hashmap. But I want to do it with lambda expression not with entrySet or sth else.

```
HashMap <Integer,Double> h=new HashMap<Integer,Double>();//I've put some key,value pairs in it 

double sum =0.0;
h.forEach((k,v)->{
    sum+=v;
});
System.out.println(sum);
```

But it says; ***Local variable sum defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final***. 
How could I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as the compiler told you, you can't modify a local variable within a lambda expression.

Instead of using `forEach`, you can create a `Stream<Double>` of the values of your `Map` and sum the elements of that `Stream`:

```
double sum = h.values()
              .stream()
              .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
              .sum();
```

Comment: Thank you I know this solution but I just tryna get lambda expressions well. For example this code works correctly but i don't get it also
double sum[] ={0};
  h2.forEach((k,v)->{
  sum[0]+=v;
  });
  System.out.println(sum[0]);

Comment: @HaticeYazıcı Using an array to overcome this restriction is usually a bad practice. The reason the code works with an array variable is that assigning to `sum[0]` doesn't change the value of `sum` (which is a reference to an array object).

Comment: Thank you, I got it well. Lastly which one is more efficient and why; solving it with entrySet or with Stream?

Comment: @HaticeYazıcı Using Streams adds some overhead, so I'm assuming it would be slower compared to some loop that iterates over the Map. Whether the difference would be significant, I have no idea.